# Where does finger connect to by default?

Tags: linux, defaults

Within our corporate network, when I run `finger` (no arguments) from a client machine, I am presented a list of users with names and the like. But when I run `finger @localhost` I get "Connection refused". So where does finger connect to by default?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to `strace finger`, on my system it gets the list of current users from

```
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

and details about each one by `stat`ing the pty

```
stat("/dev//pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
```

when run without arguments.  When you run it with `@localhost`, it tries to use the `fingerd` daemon, and since it's not 1993 any more, that's not running - hence the `connection refused`.

**Edit** when run with an argument which is a `user`, rather than `@remote-system`, it gets the information from the [GECOS field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) in `/etc/passwd` and the home directory (for files like `~/.plan`).  It doesn't have privilege, so users will need home directories and plan files you can read in order to display e.g. the plan file.  Here (also from `strace`) you see it both trying, and failing, to open some of these files in another user's directory, which is mode 750 (and I'm not in her group):

```
lstat("/home/cby/.pgpkey", 0x7fff52fcec60) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
lstat("/home/cby/.project", 0x7fff52fcec60) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
lstat("/home/cby/.plan", 0x7fff52fcec60) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: I didn't even know that you can use this as  alternative to `who`, I've only ever used it in conjunction with `fingerd` and therefore, both `finger` and `fingerd` aren't even installed on my systems anymore.

Comment: Thanks for changing 1988 to 1993, makes me feel less old ;-) But what I don't understand then is, if it does not connect, where does it get data about people not logged in (`finger offlineusername`)? Though I didn't ask that in my post. Should I edit the question or post a new one?

Comment: @Sven no worries, I guessed it was so!  I put it *back* on all the systems I admin, because I find the output much more human-friendly than `who`'s.  But I don't run (or install) `fingerd`; that would be weird.

Comment: @Paul no worries - I felt '93 was a bit more honest, since that's about when I stopped running `fingerd` on internet-connected systems.  I've updated my answer in line with your supplementary question; I think a comment is OK for such a small additional point, rather than opening a whole new question.  By the way, I notice you're new to SF (welcome!); please take a moment to take our [help tour](http://serverfault.com/tour), if you haven't already, and learn about accepting answers to questions (amongst other things).

Comment: oops, fixed now.

Comment: @MadHatter: I love this small nuggets of knowledge - just tested it and I've now added `finger` to my puppet package list  :)

Comment: @Sven I gave a mod a "*nugget of knowledge*" - seriously, that's made my day!

Comment: @MadHatter: :-)

Comment: "ignore Sven's apparent incredulity, above" There is nothing from Sven above your answer. What are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling he made a comment on the original question that he has since deleted; don't sweat it!  (I've edited my answer to be less confusing, in the light of that deletion.)

Comment: @MadHatter Yeah, I figured it was something like that, but it just really didn't make any sense to me. Thanks for cleaning it up!

Comment: I miss being able to reach out and touch someone.

Comment: To add a little extra perspective, note that the `finger` command first appeared in 3BSD, and the TCP/IP stack didn't come along until 4.2BSD. `finger` is a local user lookup tool that got extended to support remote lookups, not a network tool with a special local mode.

Comment: @MadHatter The first time I got to use a Unix system fingerd was still running on most (if not all) machines in the department. That was in 1997.